# Reutilize maps markers for weighted heatMaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this functions to get markers via Ajax, and draw it in a map_canvas div. That works perfectly, and I'm trying to reuse the "gmarkers" variable to create a heatmap...with no luck. How can I create a heatmap with this data?

I prefer to use the same data I'm loading with this function weighting the heatmap by variable: llamados.

How can I start?

```
var gmarkers = [];
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: mapCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    current_zoom = map.getZoom();
    var myControl = document.getElementById('descripcion');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(myControl);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var marker, i;
var myLatLng;

function CreateMarker (obj, i) {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj['lat'], obj['lon']);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: obj['nodo'],
        llamados: obj['llamados'],
        icon: obj['icono'],
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent('Nodo: ' + obj['nodo'] + '; Llamados: ' + obj['llamados']);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    gmarkers.push(marker);
}

function ejecutarAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        cache: false,
        // data: params,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 0,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'traerLlamados.php',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                var data = data;
                var obj;
                cantidad=Object.keys(data).length;

                    for(var i in data){
                                CreateMarker(data[i]);
                         };
                    }

            else {
                alert('No data');
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  that shows what you have working now, including some test data (the AJAX call to return data is probably not needed to address your question, but some sample data is).  How are you trying to configure the heatmap?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of data, I assumed (wrongly) that the method CreateMarker with the ajax fields (obj: lat,lon,nodo,llamados,icono) was sufficient, I'll try the answer given and if not complete the question (obviously I take your suggestion for my next question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your existing code, you should be able to add a heatmap to the map (after the markers are loaded) by doing:

```
var heatmapArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
  heatmapArray.push({location: gmarkers[i].getPosition(), weight: gmarkers[i].llamados});
}
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: heatmapArray
});
heatmap.setMap(map);
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k9x9fzpa/9/)

#### Code snippet:

```js
var gmarkers = [];
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447);

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: mapCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
  current_zoom = map.getZoom();
  var myControl = document.getElementById('descripcion');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(myControl);

  for (var i = 0; i < heatMapData.length; i++) {

    // Translate into obj expected by CreateMarker
    var obj = {
      lat: heatMapData[i].location.lat(),
      lon: heatMapData[i].location.lng(),
      nodo: "nodo" + i,
      llamados: heatMapData[i].weight,
      icono: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
    }
    CreateMarker(obj, i);
  }
  var heatmapArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    heatmapArray.push({
      location: gmarkers[i].getPosition(),
      weight: gmarkers[i].llamados
    });
  }
  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatmapArray
  });
  heatmap.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var marker, i;
var myLatLng;

function CreateMarker(obj, i) {
  myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj['lat'], obj['lon']);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: obj['nodo'],
    llamados: obj['llamados'],
    icon: obj['icono'],
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent('Nodo: ' + obj['nodo'] + '; Llamados: ' + obj['llamados']);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  gmarkers.push(marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
/* Data points defined as a mixture of WeightedLocation and LatLng objects */
var heatMapData = [{
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447),
  weight: 0.5
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
  weight: 1
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443),
  weight: 2
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441),
  weight: 3
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439),
  weight: 2
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
  weight: 10
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435),
  weight: 0.5
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447),
  weight: 3
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445),
  weight: 2
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
  weight: 5
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441),
  weight: 0.5
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
  weight: 1
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437),
  weight: 2
}, {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435),
  weight: 3
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you geocodezip it shows markers and heatmap but the heatmap dont get modified by changing the weight, if I set a weight of 1000 the expected result is a big red shadow around that marker. I'm going to apply your solution to show both maps, still looking for weighting the footprint of the heatmap points. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: There was a typo.  However 1000 causes the rest of the points to be scaled down so you can't see their heatmaps.

Comment: I know I will not use 1000, it was an exaggerated example of what I was trying to achieve. Im curious of where was the typo. Thank you!!